# One broker can't connect to ZooKeeper service

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

So I have 4 Kafka replicas and 4 ZooKeeper replicas running in my cluster, all ZooKeepers are running fine and 3 Kafka pods running fine, but there is 1 Kafka pod that constantly gets this error:

> ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception during startup.
> (kafka.Kafka$) [main] kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException:
> Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING

Why is 1 pod failing to find ZooKeeper?

I tried deleting the Pod multiple times, also tried scaling down to 3 replicas in ZooKeeper and Kafka. This also did not work, it just deleted 1 healthy pod and 1 still giving the timeout error.

Comment: You need to share your Kafka and Zookeeper properties. Are you using Strimzi?

Answer (score 0):

> 4 ZooKeeper replicas

Never run an even number of Zookeepers. 3 or 5 is the recommendation for small-medium Kafka clusters, as written in Kafka Definitive Guide book.

Comment: But this also happens in my cluster which is running 3 kafka pods and 5 zookeeper pods, any other idea why it could happen?

Comment: 5 Zookeepers isn't really needed for small Kafka clusters. Plus, Kafka no longer requires Zookeeper at all, as of version 3.3. You'll need to edit your question to include the Kubernetes manifests. I recommend you to use Strimzi, however